# React Native, For Loop shows only the first Array Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, for-loop

I have this function which supposed to loop through 20 elements of (smn) Array to show the elements that meets the IF condition, with this code I got only the first array elements:

```
    renderSMN() {
    const smn = ['fb', 'twt', 'snp', 'ins', 'ytu', 'lnk', 'tik', 'beh', 'pin', 'tmp', 'www', 'eml', 'wap', 'msg', 'tlg', 'lin', 'wch', 'skp', 'snd', 'oth'];
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        //alert(this.state.data.smu_+smn[i]);
        alert(i);
        if (this.state.data.smu_+smn[i] != "") {
            return (
                <View style={{ margin: 5 }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('Result', { postId: item.uid, otherParam: 'Pass whatever you want here', });
                    }}>
                        <Image source={{ uri: 'http://localhost/rest/smn/' + smn[i] + '.png' }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100, right: 0, }} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>{i}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
```

This how I get the Data from JSON file:

```
        fetch('http://localhost/rest/api/single_read.php/?id=' + postId, {
        method: 'GET'
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            console.log(responseJson);
            this.setState({
                data: responseJson
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're exiting the loop early by returning the JSX on the first `smn` that matches the condition. What you may want to do instead is to return an array of JSXes, some of them being falsy.
You can do this by [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)ing the `smn`s to JSX. Note that when working with arrays of JSX, it's recommended to explicitly pass a `key` prop to each array element's root element.

```js
renderSMN() {
    const smn = ['fb', 'twt', 'snp', 'ins', 'ytu', 'lnk', 'tik', 'beh', 'pin', 'tmp', 'www', 'eml', 'wap', 'msg', 'tlg', 'lin', 'wch', 'skp', 'snd', 'oth'];
    return smn.map((s, i) => {
        alert(i);
        if (this.state.data.smu_+s != "") {
            return (
                <View style={{ margin: 5 }} key={i}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => {
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('Result', { postId: item.uid, otherParam: 'Pass whatever you want here', });
                        }}
                    >
                        <Image source={{ uri: 'http://localhost/rest/smn/' + s + '.png' }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100, right: 0, }} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>{i}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Note that if the condition doesn't hold, the function returns `undefined` implicitly, which is falsy.

Comment: I use this.state.data.smu_nam to show to JSON item (Name) in render but it does not work in the Function that I made.

Comment: I don't understand your question @HowardJohn

Comment: I've used this.state.data.smu_nam to display data from JSON, it works fine inside <View> , but not else where.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration you return from the renderSMN without continuing the loop.

I'd advise doing something like.

```
return smn.map(smnItem => {
    if(this.state.data.smu_+smnItem !== '') {
        return (...)
    } 

    return null;
});
```

instead of the for loop. Which allows to to still use the return keyword

You'd want to replace instances of smn[i] with smnItem